# All I did today was hang around the house and watch TV

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

I saw this sentence yesterday and wonder why it uses the bare infinitive (hang/watch) instead of the to-infinitive (to hang/to watch).

> All I did today was hang around the house and watch TV.

Any grammar rules or definitive source of this usage I can check?

Comment: What are you trying to compare it to? *All I did today was hang around the house **to** watch TV*?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm trying to compare the sentence to "All I did today was *to* hang around the house and *(to)* watch TV."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did today was + verb

In this type of structure, both to-infinitive and bare infitive are grammatically possible.  However, the use of bare infinitive is more commom and idiomatic.

All I did today was hang around the house and watch TV.  (More idiomatic)

All I did today was to hang around the house and (to) watch TV. (Less idiomatic)